# How do you install Sql Server on Windows IoT?

Tags: windowsiot

I need to install a DB to be able to use Nlogger to record code events. I would normally use Sql Server. Is SQL supported on IoT in-any-case, if so in what flavour?

Comment: this is not really a programming question, so it is better asked at [dba](dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Could you provide more information about the target platform? For instance is Windows 10 IoT Core or Windows 10 IoT Enterprise? What is the hardware, x86 or ARM or what? Here is an example of using SQL Server on a host that provides a web interface allowing a Windows 10 Iot Raspberry Pi to store information using web services http://port1433.com/2016/12/02/building-an-easy-button-sql-server-and-windows-10-iot/ as well as [Use a SQL Server database in a UWP app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sql-server-databases).

Answer (score 3):

Stuart, Windows IoT is really Windows IoT Core. That is it is not the Windows you get on the Desktop or server but rather more like WinRT (on phone and ARM tablets).

If you really need a database, I'd look at using SQLLite. It is the database recommended for WinRT applications. One can use it on Win IoT Core as well since it can be used with UWP Applications as described here.

[Using SQLite on the Universal Windows Platform](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2015/09/08/Using-SQLite-on-the-Universal-Windows-Platform.aspx)

Comment: What about Windows 10 IoT Enterprise? It looks like it has both the WinRT and the Win32 API. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/windows-iot however I am not sure how much of the Win32 API and what SQL Server requires from Windows.

Comment: According to [Hardware and Software Requirements for Installing SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)  in the section [Principal Editions of SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#TOP_Principal) SQL Server Standard is supported for Windows 10 IoT Enterprise as is SQL Server Express.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to connect to a remote SQL server using [System.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient). If you need a .NET Core ADO.NET-compatible provider for a database on the local device, you may want to look at [Microsoft.Data.Sqlite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite).

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using Azure or AWS (Amazon Web Services)?

Just a thought, I don't even know if you have an internet connection in your application.

You could write your REST endpoints and you would be in business.